# Underscore js replace item in object

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

Using Underscorejs, would anyone know how to simply replace one attribute of an object?

For example, if I have this:

```
var obj = {
 "id" : 123,
 "date" : 142002020,
 "name" : "somename",
 "active" : 1
}
```

Now I want to set active to 0;

I could use `_.collect` and check for 'active' then update it and return to a new variable, but it seems like there's a better way, I'm just not seeing it.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you just `obj['active'] = 0`, you don't need underscore for changing an property.

**EDIT**

If you need to find a nested key maybe you could use a recursive function.

```
var obj = {
   'foo' : {
      'bar' : {
         'active' : 1
      }
   }
}

function replaceKey (obj, key, value) {
   var _obj = _(obj)

    _obj.each(function (v, k) {
      if (k === key) {
         obj[k] = value
      } else if (obj[k] === Object(obj[k])) {
         replaceKey(obj[k], key, value)
      }
   })

   return _obj;
}

console.log('should be active:', obj.foo.bar.active === 1)
replaceKey(obj, 'active', 0)
console.log('should not be active:', obj.foo.bar.active === 0)
```

Comment: Probably because they want to chain that with other calls.

Comment: Sorry, yeah my example is bad.  Yes that would be fine, but sometimes its nested deeper and I don't know how deep, like, ideally it would "find" a key, no matter how deep it is and change it's value.